# VueJs dynamic component chunks (laravel-mix/webpack) loading url changes after i go to a subpage

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

i am developing a multipage web application using Laravel and VueJs.
resources are compiled using Laravel-mix (webpack wrapper)

i am lazy loading components in vuejs route

```
{
    path: "/auth",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "site" */'./components/Site'),
    children: [
        {
            name: "login",
            path: "login",
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */'./components/auth/Login'),
            meta: {
                title: "Login to your account",
                breadcrumbs: [{ name: "Login", active: true }]
            }
        },
        {
            name: "register",
            path: "register",
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "register" */'./components/auth/Register'),
            meta: {
                title: "Register",
                breadcrumbs: [{ name: "Register", active: true }]
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

my `webpack.mix.js` is as follows,

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        publicPath: "public/",
        chunkFilename: mix.inProduction() ? "js/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js" : "js/chunks/[name].js"
    },
});
```

i am getting the chunks in my `projectfolder/public/js/chunks/` which is right.

but my problem is, after loading home/root page,

i go to `http://projecturl/auth/login` that works fine. because the `login.js` chunk is loading from `http://projecturl/public/js/chunks/login.js`

but then when i go to `http://projecturl/auth/register` **it doesnt work** !
because the `register.js` chunk is loading from `http://projecturl/auth/public/js/chunks/login.js`

**it seems the chunk loading url changes every time i go to a any subpage**. and that subpage url becomes the chunk public path.

Please help.